# Проверка результатов кросс-валидации с cross_val_score

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Есть таблица из N столбцов.

Делаю так:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as KNC

index=data[:0]       ## *выделение ненужного*
dataK = data[list(range(1,14))]          ## *и нужного*
kf=KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 42) ## *задание генератора разбиений* 
estimator = KNC(n_neighbors=k) ## *классификатор*
results = cross_val_score(estimator=estimator, X=dataK, y=index, cv=kf) ## *проверка качества*
print(results.mean())
```

Получаю в итоге:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [178, 0]

То ессть, несовпадение входа и образца.

В чем проблема?

Comment: Какой тип у объекта “data”?

Comment: data = pd.read_csv('wine.data', header=None)

dataK = data[list(range(1,14))]

двумерный числовой массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно разбили данные. Попробуйте так:

```
X = data.iloc[:, 1:]
y = data.iloc[:, 0]
results = cross_val_score(estimator=estimator, X=X, y=y, cv=kf)
```

[Документация по индексированию и работе со срезами в Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: Метод работает, спасибо. Но непонятно, в чем принципиальная разница, ведь и в моем случае указываются нужные части таблицы.

Comment: @Eugene_Venev, вы неправильно используете срезы для DataFrame. Советую после разбивки проверять размерность датасетов: print(dataK.shape, index.shape)